# Minimize styling for html tables

Tags: html, css, email, clients

I am working on HTML Emails and facing one issue, I have style tags defined in the  section. 
Outlook displays this email message with the required styling but Gmail doesn’t. This is because Gmail’s Preprocessor removes the styles contained in  section. 
Seems Inline styling is the only option to work with Gmail but it is not affordable because I require css styles applied to  and  and I have about 9000 table rows, 6-7 columns. So bunch of extra text will get generated if I go for inline styling with might exceed the size limit of email clients. Is there a way to figure out how can we achieve both i.e. not exceeding the size as well as proper rendering of message in Gmail.

Comment: There are online tools that convert a stylesheet styles to inline styles. Beware that email parsers use CSS 1.1. [here's](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps) a resource with things to keep in mind when designing emails for gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline styles are the only option for Gmail.

Have a look here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

This is also a good resource: https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1

As noted there:

> Commonly stripped elements include JavaScript, object and embed tags,
>   and Flash. Gmail goes one step further and strips out both the head
>   and body tags, as well as any style tags in an email.

and:

> The quickest way to insure your email campaign renders properly in
>   Gmail is to place your most important styles inline.